# Launch4j exception error

Tags: java, jar, exe, executable, launch4j

I have a Java jar of which I would like to turn into a .exe file for Windows. Only problem is that I get the following error when building it through Launch4j on Linux `net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Desktop/launch4j/bin/windres": error=2, No such file or directory`. I am not completely sure what is wrong, as I have tried to use the same Launch4j setup along with the same jar with Launch4j but on a Mac instead, which worked perfectly.

I have tried to search for the error on Google, but I wasn't able to get any results and on the Source-forge page with the actual download link, there are no one who have mentioned this error, at least it seems.

To me it appears as if there is something missing in the Launch4j folder? When launching the Launch4j jar to use the program, I am using the following command in the Linux terminal `Java -jar launch4j` and the program does open, the error first appears when trying to build the executable.

Comment: I think you are using the same path as you used in Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with launch4j on MACOS while using the launch4j ant task. I could solve the problem by copying (not moving) the macos executable located in the launch4j/bin to a newly created sub director launch4j/bin/mac. So I have got:
-launch4j/bin
 ld
 windres
 -mac
  ld
  windres